# Searching google with query pulled from TextView

Tags: java, android, search, textview

I would like to add a button to my app which would search google using a specific query. The query would be pulled from the word displayed in a TextView.

Here's my TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_random_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#FF8800"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    tools:context=".ImHungry" />
```

Comment: what have you tried? we wont do the work for you, we will help you with your problem.

Comment: Intent browser=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browser.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com/search?q=qwerty"));
startActivity(browser);

Comment: haven't been able to change that qwerty to something that is pulled from TextView

Comment: String search = Textview.getText().toString(); 
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=" + search); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the comments you gave this will do the trick.

```
String search = text_random_text.getText().toString(); 
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=" + search); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks for all your help, all is well except this one error..hmmm http://oi45.tinypic.com/vf9saw.jpg